# Is there any Penetration Testing or Security Audit guidelines (Such as OWASP) for Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, resources, penetration-testing

Infact, I ask you to help me with the first step, means any website or tutorial about Kubernetes penetration testing.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is unfortunately too broad to get a meaningful answer from StackOverflow. The best way that any of us can recommend is try a reading/watching/etc a little bit of everything and run with whatever works best for you.

Comment: You're right. Infact I ask you to help me with the first step, means any website or tutorial about Kubernetes penetration testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended you to go through the link [Kube pentesting starter](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/pentesting/pentesting-kubernetes) and [kube-hunter](https://blog.aquasec.com/kube-hunter-kubernetes-penetration-testing) to know more about penetration testing in k8's.